# Smartcards for Dummies

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, professional-education

Are there any defacto resources for understanding the basics of smart cards?

My problem is that I don't know what I don't know about the technology.

Any good primers?

Comment: Are you looking more for hardware or software information?  I've managed an entire career (so far) knowing alot about provisioning PKI for Smart Cards, while knowing less than 10 bullet points about the hardware side...

Comment: @bethlaksmi hmm.  Both preferably, but software at a minimum.

Comment: If you're looking for the real basics, you can always check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to read straight from standards, and you are looking something in book form, this is a nice primer, (fairly) entry level into smart card security: [http://www.amazon.com/Smart-Cards-Tokens-Security-Applications/dp/1441944265](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441944265) . It's written by two university professors and is the course book on a msc course about smart cards.
For a more comprehensive book on the subject (but maybe a bit beyond what you need) I suggest this one: [http://www.amazon.com/Smart-Card-Handbook-Wolfgang-Rankl/dp/0470743670](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470743670)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you are looking for there is a lot of technologies covering the smart card topic. Some of them coming to my mind:

- **ISO 7816**: cards with contact http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816.aspx
- **ISO 14443**: contactless smart cards
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443
- **PKCS#15**: Cryptographic Token Information Format Standard http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2141
- **PKCS#11**: Cryptographic Token Interface Standard
  http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2133

Comment: @Thomas Great links, but I think the books linked to by @john will be easier to read. :)

Comment: @SteveS: hey, I am not the author of this answer ! Credits go to @Jcs. I just fixed a couple of typographic errors.

Answer (score 3):

OpenSC project has also lots of information and further pointers. And you're most welcome to ask for help on the mailing list as well.

http://www.opensc-project.org